# How to ask user re-enter until the value is true?

Tags: java

How to ask user re-enter until the value is true? I get error for this code. Is it I cant store the re-entered value in the same variable? Anyone can provide some example for me to understand better? I need to ask user keep re-enter until the email address entered is match with the pattern

Comment: You'll need to use a loop.

Comment: What error do you get? Try a while loop

Answer (score 1):

Replacing your `if` with a simple `while` loop should do the trick:

```java
String emailAddress = null;
// Set valid to false initially to ensure we're entering the while block
boolean validEmail = false;

while(!validEmail) {
 // read email
 emailAddress = input.next();
 // check validity
 validEmail = validEmailAddress(emailAddress);
 if(!validEmail){
   // if invalid warn the user and loop
   System.out.println("Invalid Email Address, Please re-enter Email Address: ");
  }
}

System.out.println("Thanks! Your email is:" +emailAddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

if -> while. That's it.

```
System.out.print("Email Address: ");
String emailAddress = input.next();
while (!validEmailAddress(emailAddress)) {
    System.out.print("Invalid Email Address, Please re-enter Email Address: ");
    emailAddress = input.next();
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("Thanks! Your email is: " + emailAddress)
```

You are a great fellow, as you moved the validation check into a separate method.